# Facebook API restserver error with likes and comments

Tags: facebook, get

I'm having this strange problem: I have a link for a picture and i want to display it on my wall. Now i want to know how many times it was liked, shared and commented on.  Let's say my picture url is http://mywebsite.com/mypicture.jpg?468

Now, I share this picture on my wall, I get likes, shares and comments.

If i'm using the http://api.facebook.com/restserver.php?method=links.getStats&urls=... i can see the shares, but not the likes or comments number.

Why is that? Do you think it's because of the ?468 after the .jpg?  If so, why is that happing and only the shares are counted, and not the likes or comments?

Answer (score 0):

For starters, you should be using the Graph API.  The [restserver.php](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/rest/links.getStats/) file you are pointing at is deprecated at this point.

Comment: Could you please be more specific? Could you please give me an example? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You will want to use the send (or like) plugin from Facebook. The REST API is deprecated (no longer supported and will be pulled completely from Facebook at anytime).

Then your url being shared will get a id from facebook and the stats tracked.  Here's some examples: http://graph.facebook.com/?ids=CocaCola or http://graph.facebook.com/?ids=http://www.coca-cola.com